# pandas group by column values with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe , i need to group by 'sev' column with conditions like 1&2 , 3, 4&5 and find its count.

Is there any method?

i have tired this , but its giving for each separate values in sev column

```
df.groupby(['sev']).ids.agg('count').to_frame('count').reset_index()
```

pandas dataFrame -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ids': {0: 'D1791272223',  1: 'V25369085223',  2: 'V25117230523',  3: 'V25104327323',  4: 'V24862169823',  5: 'P3944221523',  6: 'V24776335823',  7: 'V24722584123',  8: 'V24716191923',  9: 'V24575876123',  10: 'V24791923'}, 'status': {0: 'Resolved',  1: 'Resolved',  2: 'Resolved',  3: 'Resolved',  4: 'Open',  5: 'Open',  6: 'Closed',  7: 'Resolved',  8: 'Resolved',  9: 'Open',  10: 'Resolved'}, 'action': {0: 'Comment',  1: 'Implementation',  2: 'Comment',  3: 'Implementation',  4: 'Comment',  5: 'Implementation',  6: 'Comment',  7: 'Comment',  8: 'Implementation',  9: 'Comment',  10: 'Implementation'}, 'sev': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 3, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 1, 10: 5}})
```

```
| ids          | status   | action         | sev |
|--------------|----------|----------------|-----|
| D1791272223  | Resolved | Comment        | 3   |
| V25369085223 | Resolved | Implementation | 2   |
| V25117230523 | Resolved | Comment        | 1   |
| V25104327323 | Resolved | Implementation | 3   |
| V24862169823 | Open     | Comment        | 4   |
| P3944221523  | Open     | Implementation | 4   |
| V24776335823 | Closed   | Comment        | 3   |
| V24722584123 | Resolved | Comment        | 2   |
| V24716191923 | Resolved | Implementation | 2   |
| V24575876123 | Open     | Comment        | 1   |
| V24791923    | Resolved | Implementation | 5   |
```

Expected output

```
| sev    | count | Open count | Closed and   Resolved count |
|--------|-------|------------|-----------------------------|
| 1&2    | 5     | 1          | 4                           |
| 3      | 3     | 0          | 3                           |
| 4&5    | 3     | 2          | 1                           |
```

Comment: Maybe you could try building on this `pd.pivot_table(a, index='sev', aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique())).reset_index()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you need to aggregate severity levels into less categories, which can be done with `pd.cut` since `sev` is numeric and you want to on continuous intervals. If it was not numeric or the intervals were discontinuous (e.g. 1&4, 2, 3&5), you would need `df.replace` with a mapping dictionary.

Then the reshaping can be done with `df.pivot_table` or "manually" with `groupby/unstack`. I prefer `groupby` since it is more flexible in other situations.

```
df['sev_group'] = pd.cut(df['sev'], bins=[0, 2, 3, 5],
    labels=['1&2', '3', '4&5'])


summary = df.groupby(['sev_group', 'status']).size().unstack()
# or
# summary = df.pivot_table(values='ids', index='sev_group',
    # columns='status', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)


summary['count'] = summary.sum(axis=1)
summary['Closed/Resolved'] = summary['Closed'] + summary['Resolved']
summary = summary[['count', 'Open', 'Closed/Resolved']]
```

Output

```
status     count  Open  Closed/Resolved
sev_group
1&2            5     1                4
3              3     0                3
4&5            3     2                1
```